# How to - piping the output of one program to the input of another (capslocker) using emacs - haskell mode?

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-platform, haskell-mode

capslocker.hs has following code:

```
import Control.Monad  
import Data.Char  
main = forever $ do  
    putStr "Give me some input: "  
    l <- getLine  
    putStrLn $ map toUpper l
```

haiku.txt has following contents:

```
I'm a lil' teapot  
What's with that airplane food, huh?  
It's so small, tasteless
```

In the terminal, I am able to do:

```
optimight@optimight:~$ cat haiku.txt  
I'm a lil' teapot  
What's with that airplane food, huh?  
It's so small, tasteless
```

And this:

```
optimight@optimight:~$ cat haiku.txt | ./capslocker  
Give me some input: I'M A LIL' TEAPOT  
Give me some input: WHAT'S WITH THAT AIRPLANE FOOD, HUH?  
Give me some input: IT'S SO SMALL, TASTELESS  
Give me some input: capslocker: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
```

**How to test the same (as done in terminal) in emacs23 - haskell mode? Please guide.**

Please note that, in emacs - haskell mode, I have tried following:

```
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help  
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.  
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.  
Loading package base ... linking ... done.  
Prelude> :load "/home/optimight/capslocker.hs"  
[1 of 1] Compiling Main      ( /home/optimight/capslocker.hs, interpreted )  
Ok, modules loaded: Main.  
*Main> cat haiku.txt | ./capslocker  
<interactive>:3:15: parse error on input `|'   
*Main>
```

Comment: Another useless use of cat... `./capslocker <haiku.txt`. ;-)

Comment: @DanielWagner : Sir, I am an absolute beginner. Just going through LYAH for good. What are actual scenario/s where cat can be used properly?

Comment: Not really a Haskell thing, but... ["The purpose of cat is to concatenate (or 'catenate') files. If it's only one file, concatenating it with nothing at all is a waste of time, and costs you a process."](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ghci prompt, you can call shell commands by prefixing with `:!`.

```
*Main> :! cat haiku.txt | ./capslocker
```

It ought to work the same in emacs.